# Gatling.io scala socket.io

Tags: scala, websocket, socket.io, gatling

I write test on gatling and try send socket.io event to server. But get error when build project.

[My test](https://gist.github.com/pbezpal/50c5cda370c4e1b49515dae109bfb55b)

Error

```
/home/pbezpal/roschat/testing-roschat/load-testing/Gatling/src/test/scala/ServerLoad.scala:49:17
type mismatch;
 found   : io.socket.emitter.Emitter
 required: io.gatling.commons.validation.Validation[io.gatling.core.session.Session]
       socket.on( Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Listener {
```

How to write correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it

```
.exec(session => {
       val obj = new JSONObject()
       val aknowledge = null
       obj.put("login", "${login}")
       obj.put("password", "${password}")
       obj.put("APILevel", "${level}")
       optConnect.forceNew = false
       optConnect.timeout = 10000
       val socket = IO.socket( socketUrl, optConnect )
       val printListener: Emitter.Listener = new Emitter.Listener {
         override def call(args: AnyRef*): Unit = {
         }
       }
       socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, printListener)
       socket.connect()
       socket.emit("login",obj)
       session
      }
     )
```

But now $ {login} is sent to the server and not the value from the csv file. How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: the `obj.put` method doesn't know anything about the Gatling EL - you're going to have to get the value out of the session manually using `session("login").as[String]`